# A peculiar series involving $\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, pi

A mathematical Facebook group posted a picture with the following claimed identity:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1+14 n+76 n^{2}+168 n^{3}}{2^{20 n}}\binom{2n}{n}^{7}=\frac{32}{\pi^{3}}.
$$

they didn't provide any source for this claim, but it appears that it might be a conjecture.

Is this a familiar series? If so, what are its origins?

Comment: Looks Ramanujany

Comment: Boris Gourevitch conjectured this formula by using integer relations algorithms. See [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1087568026).

Comment: @Zacky: make that an answer?

Comment: Jesus Guillera proved many series dealing with $1/\pi^2$. But this one dealing with $1/\pi^3$ does not seem to be proved so far.