# Using Ramanujan-type series for $1/\pi^m$ to find formulas for $\zeta(2),\, \zeta(3),\, \zeta(4)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, riemann-zeta, pi, pochhammer-symbol

As described by Guillera in "[*Ramanujan Series with a Shift*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.02023)", one nice thing about Ramanujan-type $1/\pi^m$ formulas is by "shifting" them, they can yield a *second* value which may also have a closed-form. For $m>1$, only **12** non-trivial ones are known and we will apply the technique to the first half. Let $(x)_n$ be the [*Pochhammer symbol*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html).

---

$$F_1(k) = \small\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\big(\tfrac12+k\big)_n^5}{\big(1+k\big)_n^5}\,\left(20(n + k)^2 + 8(n + k) + 1\right)\,\left(\frac{-1}{\;2^2}\right)^n$$

then $\,F_1(0) = \dfrac{8}{\pi^2}\,$ and $\,F_1\big(\tfrac12\big) = 7\,\color{red}{\zeta(3)}.$

---

$$F_2(k) = \small\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\big(\tfrac12+k\big)_n^5}{\big(1+k\big)_n^5}\,\left(820(n + k)^2 + 180(n + k) + 13 \right)\,\left(\frac{-1}{\,2^{10}}\right)^n$$

then $\,F_2(0) = \dfrac{128}{\pi^2}\,$ and $\,F_2\big(\tfrac12\big) = 256\,\color{red}{\zeta(3)}.$

---

$$F_3(k) = \small\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\big(\tfrac12+k\big)_n^3\,\big(\tfrac13+k\big)_n\,\big(\tfrac23+k\big)_n}{\big(1+k\big)_n^5}\,\left( 74(n + k)^2 + 27(n + k) + 3 \right)\,\left(\frac34\right)^{3n}$$

then $\,F_3(0) = \dfrac{48}{\pi^2}\,$ and $\,F_3\big(\tfrac12\big) = \dfrac{16\pi^2}{3}.$

---

$$F_4(k) = \small\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\big(\tfrac12+k\big)_n^3\,\big(\tfrac14+k\big)_n\,\big(\tfrac34+k\big)_n}{\big(1+k\big)_n^5}\,\left( 120(n + k)^2 + 34(n + k) + 3 \right)\,\left(\frac1{2^4}\right)^n$$

then $\,F_4(0) = \dfrac{32}{\pi^2}\,$ and $\,F_4\big(\tfrac12\big) =  \dfrac{16\pi^2}{3}.$ (Same as above.)

---

$$F_5(k) = \small\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\big(\tfrac12+k\big)_n^7}{\big(1+k\big)_n^7}\,\left(168(n + k)^3 + 76(n + k)^2 + 14(n + k) + 1 \right)\,\left(\frac1{2^6}\right)^{n}$$

then $\,F_5(0) = \dfrac{2^5}{\color{blue}{\pi^3}}\,$ and $\,F_5\big(\tfrac12\big) = \dfrac{\pi^4}{2}.$

The first relation was found by Boris Gourevitch around 2002. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3533322/4781).

---

$$F_6(k) = \small\sum_{n=0}^\infty\, s(n)\,\left( 43680(n + k)^4 + 20632(n + k)^3 + 4340(n + k)^2 + 466(n + k) + 21 \right)\,\left(\frac1{2^{12}}\right)^{n}$$

then $\,F_6(0) = \dfrac{2^{11}}{\color{blue}{\pi^4}}\,$ and $\,F_6\big(\tfrac12\big) = \dfrac{2^{10}\pi^4}{15},\,$ where $s(n) = \dfrac{\big(\tfrac12+k\big)_n^7\,\big(\tfrac14+k\big)_n\,\big(\tfrac34+k\big)_n}{\big(1+k\big)_n^9}.$

The first relation was found by Jim Cullen around 2010. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4795715/4781). After 2010, it seems no higher Ramanujan-type $1/\pi^m$ formula has been discovered.

---

**Question**: In Guillera's cited paper on $1/\pi$, some of the second values are conjectured. Likewise, some of the first and second values in this post are also conjectured. Anyone can prove a pair, especially if it involves $\zeta(3)$?

Comment: Nice Post. Here is something that might interest you.
$$F(k)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{16-128\left(n+k\right)+384\left(n+k\right)^{2}-512\left(n+k\right)^{3}+255\left(n+k\right)^{4}}{\left(n+k\right)^{4}}\right)\binom{2n+2k}{n+k}^{-4}$$

$$F(0)=-1, F\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi^4}{256}, F\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{2^83^2\pi^4}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{12},F\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{2^{12}\pi^2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{8},F\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)=\frac{1}{2^{32/3}\pi^4}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{12}$$

Comment: @MiracleInvoker That is certainly interesting! You used $k = 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/6$ which are the same rationals in Ramanujan’s theory of elliptic functions in alternative bases. Did you check if the six formulas above have closed-forms for the other $k$?

Comment: I tried checking for other values but I do not have a powerful Integer Relation Algorithms, so was not able to go further. Wolfram only gave these.

Comment: @MiracleInvoker In what context did you find that quartic polynomial? I checked its discriminant $d$ and it is **very** nice as just $d = -2^{20}$ [given by Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FactorInteger%5BDiscriminant%5B16%E2%88%92128n%2B384n%5E2%E2%88%92512n%5E3%2B255n%5E4%2Cn%5D%5D).

Comment: I originally used FindIntegerNullVector to get the relation for $-1$, I think I was able to get many like these. But I decided to apply the shifting after I was informed about it from you and surprisingly these results came.
Also,
$$F\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{2^8}{3^4}\pi^8\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{-12}$$

Comment: @MiracleInvoker I checked. We have, $$\quad F(1/2) = a\,\pi^4\\ F(1/3) F(2/3) = b\,\pi^4\\ F(1/4) F(3/4) = c\,\pi^4\\ F(1/6) F(5/6) = d\,\pi^4$$ where $(a,b,c,d)$ are rational numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149468/discussion-between-miracle-invoker-and-tito-piezas-iii).

Comment: @MiracleInvoker We also have, $$F(1/5)F(4/5) = \left(\frac{2}{3\cdot5}\right)^4 \left(\frac{\pi}{\tan(\pi/5)}\right)^4$$ $$F(1/7)F(6/7) = \left(\frac{3}{5\cdot7}\right)^4 \left(\frac{\pi}{\tan(\pi/7)}\right)^4$$ The trigonometric functions explain why $(a,b,c,d)$ are rational, but algebraic for higher versions. But to isolate $F(1/5)$ or $F(1/7)$ is more difficult.

Comment: Is this one known?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{144-543n+744n^{2}-435n^{3}+90n^{4}}{n^{3}}\right)\binom{2n}{n}\binom{n}{n/2}^{-4}=\pi^2+3$$

Comment: @MiracleInvoker I don't think so. There is only one Ramanujan-type formula with a quartic polynomial as a numerator, and they normally don't have a denominator (like the $n^3$ for this new formula) And the numerator has the common factor $3$, so the sum actually is $\dfrac{\pi^2}3+1$.

Comment: @MiracleInvoker Also, it seems better to let $n\to2(m+k)$ to get rid of fractions in the binomials. Then the formula has two values, for $k=0$ and $k=1/2$, both involving $\pi^2$.

Comment: Does " blue " imply unproven ? It is not clear to me which ones are proven or not.

Comment: @mick I used the blue color to emphasize the exponent was $m>2$ but, yes, they are unproven too. (If I remember correctly, a few of the $m=2$ are unproven as well.)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I was thinking about https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981073/is-there-an-integral-for-frac1-zeta3
and
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991661/understanding-when-the-multiplication-of-two-definite-integrals-gives-unity

Where we have sums and integrals for zeta(3).  I wonder if they are related to the above sums for zeta(3) AND I wonder if these hypergeo can result in 1/zeta(3).